# Sending APNs iOS push notifications via proxy using Pushy Java library

Tags: java, ios, proxy, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to place a proxy between my backend server(Redhat, Tomcat) and APNs.

The library used to generate the push notifications is Pushy https://github.com/relayrides/pushy

I'm able to get the server to send push notification traffic to somewhere other than APNs, so calling a proxy is not an issue.

**Problems:**
The version of Pushy I use communicates with APNs via a old binary protocol(TCP) instead of Http/2 which is used in the newer versions, due to this non-standard protocol, Apache or some other common proxy choices will not work.

**Question:**

- Anyone know any proxy that will work in my case?
- If I have to code it myself in Java, anyone have any suggestions on
  what library to use, or what's the best way to go about it?

Comment: If you are using the binary protocol then you could use a Socks proxy, but you will need to modify the pushy library. You could also look at a service, such as Urban Airship (or others) that provide a REST API that front-ends APNS

Comment: @Paulw11 Hi Paul thanks for looking at this. Am I right to think the purpose of modify pushy is so pushy can call the Socks proxy instead of APNs?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately socks isn't a transparent proxy system; you need to "socksify" the network code so that it knows it is connecting to a socks proxy and makes the right request. It would be much easier to either adopt the new push API from Apple or use a push provider with a Web services interface

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, Pushy has supported proxies [since v0.6](https://github.com/relayrides/pushy/releases/tag/pushy-0.6), released on March 28, 2016. It sounds like you have your reasons for sticking with an older version, but if you're considering making substantial code changes, it may be best to just upgrade.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we upgraded to a newer Pushy version in the end.